# Do Windows 7 time zones work correctly?

Tags: windows-7, time-zone, utc

As you see below, I changed the Windows clock time-zone from `UTC +3:30 Tehran` to `UTC +1:00 Windhoek`. As `3:30 - 1:00 = 2.30`, I expect the time to change `-2:30`, But it change `-1.30`  :

Before :

[image]

After :

[image]

Note that it works fine for other `UTC +1:00` countries. I have this problem for **Windhoek** only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TimeandDate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/namibia/windhoek) shows Windhoek is not in the time zone you think it is. It is on West African Summer Time, which is UTC+2.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windhoek) agrees.

Comment: So why it is written in the Windows time-zone `UTC +1 Windhoek`? Shouldn't it be `UTC +2 Windhoek`?

Comment: Because West African Time is at UTC+1, @Jean. Only now, it's summer time there, but that's not reflected in the list in Windows.  (And it would not make sense to show the offsets with local daylight saving time applied, as nominally Windhoek still is in UTC+1.)